# "iconv" conversion from UTF-32LE towards UTF-16LE

Tags: c++, macos, encoding, iconv

I'm building my library for 64 bit finally and now the converstion from UTF-32LE towards UTF-16LE fails on Mac OS X, C++ 64bit.

Before a step is executed, my source is the correct string, executing the iconv step clears the source and the source size.

```
iconv_t theHandle = NULL;
std::wstring source(L"My Source string to convert!");
size_t theSourceLength = source.length();
wchar_t *theSourceStart = (wchar_t*)source.c_str();
size_t sourceByteSize = sizeof(wchar_t)*theSourceLength;
UniChar* destination = new UniChar[ theSourceLength +2];
size_t destinationByteSize = sizeof(UniChar)*theSourceLength;
static const char *destinationEncoding = "UTF-16LE";
static const char *sourceEncoding = "UTF-32LE";
theHandle = iconv_open( destinationEncoding, sourceEncoding );
std::cout << "Conversion error: " << errno << std::endl;
if (errno == EINVAL)
    std::cout << "EINVAL" << std::endl;

size_t convertedSize = iconv( theHandle, (char**)&theSourceStart, &sourceByteSize, (char**)&destination, &destinationByteSize );
std::cout << "Conversion error: " << errno << std::endl;
if (errno == E2BIG)
    std::cout << "E2BIG" << std::endl;
if (errno == EILSEQ)
    std::cout << "EILSEQ" << std::endl;
if (errno == EINVAL)
    std::cout << "EINVAL" << std::endl;
```

When I stop in the debugger on the iconv line, "theSourceStart" is shown as "My Source string to convert!" and sourceByteSize == 112, when I do then one step, convertedSize == 0 and theSourceStart == L"", and sourceByteSize == 0.

Comment: Looks like everything is working as intended. Is `iconv` returning `-1`? (You should practically never look at errno if you haven't check that the function actually failed.)

Comment: The returned number of conversions is 0. The input is cleared. The output size as well. In 32 bit compilation the 32 bit UTF source is nicely converted to the 16 bit UTF destination buffer. On 64 bit the input is cleared. Is this intended? I guess it should do the conversion on 64 bit similar as on 32 bit and not clearing the source buffer. When I inspect the memory of the input buffer. Before executing, I have one character of my file path, then 3 bytes empty, then next character, etc. This is expected in 32 bit coding. Executing the iconv step overwrites this memory.

Comment: iconv updates the pointers and counts, it does not "clear the input". Again, what you are describing looks like everything is working as expected. What's wrong with the output you get?

Comment: Oops, it's working as it should. I had another problem and was still to deep in debugging. Problem is that pointers changes so you have to copy the original buffer point to see the result. So, it's indeed working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong, it's working as intended. The only thing I missed, because I was too deep in debugging, that the buffer pointers actually change by the iconv operator and that's why my source string seemed to be empty. But if I keep the original pointers, the value in destination is correctly filled and the source is untouched. So my application works.